# Terminal uses Java 7 when Java 8 is installed OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, java

I am trying to figure out why when inputting the `java -version` will give me Java 1.7, when the Java Control Panel says I'm running java 1.8, latest update as well.

I don't know how to check for duplicate java installations, or how to change where the `java` command points to. I'm a very very new OSX user, but have a little linux experience. Any help is appreciated! I apologize in advance for the spoonfeeding question.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] why when inputting the java -version will give me Java 1.7, when the Java Control Panel says I'm running java 1.8, latest update as well.

Your terminal must be defaulting to some other Java.

> I don't know how to check for duplicate java installations, or how to change where the java command points to. [...]

Use `sudo find / -name java -type f`. Ask version of each one that seems a reasonably correct install.

Comment: If you have net mounts, use `find` on a local `/DIRECTORY/` basis.

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"
```

Then `java -version` will show Java 1.8

## Java Location in macOS

Java is installed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`. You can list all the installed Java version with `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
1.8.0_05, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Set the version of Java you want to use with the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, and get the appropriate value with `/usr/libexec/java_home -v [version]`

## jEnv to switch Java version

There is a [tool specifically built to manage multiple Java versions - jenv](http://www.jenv.be/). Install the version of Java you want - on [macOS the recommended method is with Homebrew Cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask).

Add all the versions of Java available and run `rehash`

```
jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
jenv add /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
jenv rehash
```

You can set a default version

```
$ jenv versions
  system
  oracle64-1.6.0.51
  oracle64-1.7.0.40
  oracle64-1.8.0-ea
* oracle64-1.8.0.05 (set by /Users/hanxue/.jenv/version)
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

And switch versions easily

```
$ jenv local oracle64-1.7.0.40
```

#### References

[Installing Java 8 and Managing Multiple Java Versions on OSX](https://hanxue-it.blogspot.com/2014/05/installing-java-8-managing-multiple.html?q=jenv)
[How to cleanly uninstall older versions of Java on Mac](https://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2016/02/uninstall-older-version-of-java-on-os-x.html?q=jenv)

Comment: I find that my Java Control Panel lists I have Java 8, but the command you sent says I only have 6 & 7. Do you know why this is or how I could fix that?